# IocalStorage onclick add/remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script works, but when I refresh the page, the styles are applied to all elements.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="colors green"></li>
  <li class="colors grey"></li>
  <li class="colors blue"></li>
  <li class="colors yellow"></li>
  <li class="colors red"></li>
  <li class="colors purple"></li>
  <li class="colors orange"></li>
  <li class="colors brown"></li>
  <li class="colors lime"></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $("ul li").removeClass("current-color");
  $('ul li').removeAttr('id');
  $(this).addClass("current-color");

  var activeElement = $(this).text();
  console.log(activeElement);
  localStorage.setItem('current-color', activeElement);
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul li").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).text() == localStorage.getItem('current-color')) {
      $(this).addClass("current-color");
    }
  });
});
```

[[image: Before page refresh][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSmPu.png)

[image: After page refresh]

Comment: There is no text in those elements

Comment: All your `<li>` elements have no text in them so `.text()` is going to give you an empty string. So when you go to `setItem` you are setting an empty string and when you `getItem` you are getting the same empty string. Did you mean to use one of the color class names?

Comment: Your code assumes that there will be something in `localStorage` to compare against. The first time a user comes to the page, that won't be true. Your retrieval code should be wrapped in an `if` that first checks to see if `localStorage` items are event present.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have any text in those elements it's probably simpler to use the `index` of the item clicked and store that

```
const $items = $('li.colors').click(function() {
  $items.removeClass('current-color')

  $(this).addClass('current-color')
  const idx = $items.index(this);
  localStorage.setItem('current-color', idx)
});

// on page load check if item in storage and if so set class
const idx = localStorage.getItem('current-color')
if (!!idx) {
  $items.eq(+idx).addClass('current-color')
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d18p6ojs/)

---

*Note this won't work in Stack Snippet which disables localStorage*